# How to redraw the node canvas when the zoom changes on the Godot editor?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have an addon that extends `EditorPlugin` and a companion script attached to a node. The companion script draw a rectangle with a size stablished by an exported property that can be edited from a gizmo on the editor. The general idea is that the plugin shows a handle that allows to drag the visual representation of the exported property, but is the companion script the one that draws its representation on the editor. The only problem is that the node won't redraw itself when zoom changes. Is there a way to fire a redraw event when the zoom changes instead of using `_process(delta)`, since doing it every frame would increase CPU consumption dramatically for the Godot editor on a MacBook Air laptop.

This video shows the issue I'm describing https://youtu.be/wv382kOCKHY